# Nginx - If URL has query then run command?

Tags: php, nginx, varnish

I have a large ecommerce project I am working on and the vendor uses an NGINX and Varnish setup. PHP also sits inside OB cache layer and there is some memcache rules too.

I have a problem that developers face that new uploads to files require the server to be restarted or some commands on PHP to be run to see those files - this is not possible even with our dev/deploy to live site - there is always a time we need to purge fast.

I thought:

```
www.site.com/category/mens/?flush=1
www.site.com/pages/about/?flush=1
```

If flush parameter is fired then I want to run

```
php restart
varnish restart 
memcache restart
```

I was thinking

```
location = / {
    if ( query[flush]==1 ) { // pseudo code as I don't know NGINX formatting

         #service php-fpm reload;
         #service varnish restart

    }
}
```

Would this be possible. If so what is the NGINX rule to do this and can I execute those SSH commands in my vhost file. I know IfIsEvil that is not my question however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location / {
  # ...
  if ($args ~ "flush=1") {
    # do something
  }
  # ...
}
```

As for `execute shell command` you can try [lua-nginx-module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/).

```
content_by_lua 'os.execute("")';
```

Comment: Can args support multi parameters. +1 Thanks